# In React how do you pass "this" to a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Say I have a class component function like so which accesses the props

```
myFunction() {
   console.log(this.props)
}
```

if this component the renders a functional component inside it and I pass it down like so:

`<MyFunctionalComponent onChange={this.myFunction} />`

this then breaks saying `cannot read props of undefined` presumably because the concept of "this" isn't in functional land

is there an easy way to fix this except for a big refactor? or passing props in as arguments rather than `this.`

Comment: You need to bind `this` to the class method. Typically this is solved by not using a _method_ but by using a [public class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) arrow function on the class. e.g. `myFunction = () => { ... }`. This is a common problem - https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Note that it is unrelated to React, the [context is a feature of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1218980).

Comment: ah my mistake that was a typo. I was using `this`. I have edited the question now. that isn't the solution

Comment: Note that the typo isn't what we were referring to. The function context must be preserved properly.

Comment: Let's say you have `class Person{ constructor(name){ this.name = name } speak(){ return 'Hello ' + this.name } }` Then later `let bob = new Person('bob'); console.log(bob.speak());` That will work.  This won't: `const speakMethod = bob.speak; console.log(speakMethod());` The reason why this doesn't work is the same reason why you are getting your error. See [MDN on _this_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#this_in_classes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You really answered your own question.

because you are working in a class Component, you have to use 'this.' to pass the method.  What I would do is the following.

```
<MyFunctionalComponent onChange={() => this.myFunction()} />
```

Comment: You can downvote all you want, but the fact is, that in a class component you need to use this to access members.  There is no way around it.

Comment: It's possibly a typo on your part, but the way you have it, the function does nothing.

Comment: Yup, i forgot my parens()